# display mongodb data in html nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

We have saved the workers details in MongoDB. at the same time, how do we get that workers details in HTML home page?

This is my save the code:

```
//routes.js

var User = require('../app/models/user');

app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
    var myData = new User(req.body);
    myData.save()
    .then(item => {
        res.send("You are registered");
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("Unable to save to database");
    });
});
```

Comment: did You need to access the Registered Data [Which User is going to enter while Registering ]or You need to Get The All available data's or the user..

Comment: only I need  user's data   so how to do get that?.... @muthukumar

Comment: User.find({id: "particular User Id"}, (er, callback) => { console.log("Particular user details",callback)}); // to find Particular user details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the worker get API in server file you can write like this (sample code):

```
app.get("/getWorkers", (req, res) => {
    var myData = User.getUsers()
    .then(item => {
        res.send(myData);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("Unable to get");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks and what is the meaning getUsers?  is this default ahh?  I mainly take   user’s some details like user name, user address, user image so how to take that?

Comment: getUser is jst dummy here you can use mongo get function @mayoorika like u using in myData.save()

Comment: after this u can use this obj on front end in html using javascript or angularjs @mayoorika if u like my answer upvote or accept it thanks

Comment: which lines have db word ?

Comment: User.getUsers is not a function....  I get this error in your code how to solve this?